# Explain why the friction force and the component of weight down the plane are the same value

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction, relative-motion

can someone expain me why is this.

Thanks.

Comment: I sadly don't understand much from your question.

Comment: I think you need to give a little context. What plane? What situation is the plane in?

Comment: an object is inclined at a slope at 45 degrees

Comment: Your question has an incorrect premise: they aren't necessarily the same. They *might* be the same in special specific cases.

Answer (score 1):

They aren't. Frictional force down an incline is the coefficient of kinetic or static friction multiplied by mass and the acceleration of gravity and the sine of the angle of elevation. Meanwhile, the component of weight down the incline is all of the above without the coefficient of kinetic or static friction.

Comment: They must be the same if the mass is not moving.

Comment: Also: the force of static friction is only given by $\mu_S N$ when you know that the surface is exerting the maximum possible static friction force. Otherwise, there's no expression for it.